# User email attribute

Tags: jenkins, plugins, directory

Between the Active Directory Plugin and the Build User Vars Plugin i use the email attribute field so we send email messages about jobs after they have run.

Currently Ad is integrated and populates the user's details and the Build user vars plugin takes the email from this user's account to send the mail.

Does anyone know how i can change the AD lookup attribute to something else for email? I did try to manually modify the email on the user's account but it keeps getting reset to the old value. Modifying it in AD isn't an option as i would like to redirect the attribute for all users.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the latest version of the AD plugin which allows modification of email address.